# Second method scanner doesn't work

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

When I execute the code below, it takes the input correctly for `inputCar1` method, but in `inputCar2` method it executes all except the first scanner command. If I use this command twice then it works like what I expected, but it shouldn't be. For understanding well my problem, I attached my code and the output.

PrintClass:

```
package TestPackage;

/**
 * Created by km.muzahid on 03-May-15.
 */
public class PrintClass {
    public static void print(Object value){
        System.out.print(value);
    }
    public static void println(Object value)
    {
        System.out.println(value);
    }
}
```

CarClass:

```
 package TestPackage;

    /**
 * Created by km.muzahid on 03-May-15.
 */
public class CarClass {
    public String manufacturerName;
    public int CarCC;
    public float CarWeight;
    public float FuealAmount;
    public CarClass()//constructor
    {
        CarCC=0;
        CarWeight=0;
        FuealAmount=0;
    }
    public CarClass(String CarNumber,String Name,int cc,float fuel,float weight)//constructor
    {
        PrintClass ShowMassage=new PrintClass();
        ShowMassage.println(CarNumber +"Car Manufacturer Name : "+Name+"\nCC of Car : "
                +cc+"\nAmount of fuel of car : "+fuel+"\nWeight of car : "+weight);
    }
}
```

Problem code :

```
package TestPackage;
import java.util.Scanner;
/**
 * Created by km.muzahid on 03-May-15.
 */
public class testclass {
    static private PrintClass ShowMassage;
    public static Scanner MyScanner=new Scanner(System.in);
    public static CarClass car=new CarClass();
    public static CarClass car2nd=new CarClass();//create new object from carclass for 2nd car

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
      //1st car
       inputCar1("Enter for first car: ");
        CarClass SeeCar1=new CarClass("1st car details: \n",car.manufacturerName,car.CarCC,car.FuealAmount,car.CarWeight);
//        //2nd car
      CarClass See=new CarClass("2nd car details: \n",car2nd.manufacturerName,car2nd.CarCC,car2nd.FuealAmount,car2nd.CarWeight);

    }
    protected static void inputCar1(String Massege)
    {
        ShowMassage.println(Massege);
        ShowMassage.println("Enter Name of car manufactueing : ");
        car.manufacturerName=MyScanner.nextLine();
        ShowMassage.println("Enter weight of car :");
        car.CarWeight=MyScanner.nextFloat();
        ShowMassage.println("Enter the amount of Fuel : ");
        car.FuealAmount= MyScanner.nextFloat();
        ShowMassage.println("Enter the car CC : ");
        car.CarCC= MyScanner.nextInt();
        inputCar2("Enter For 2nd Car : ");
    }
    protected static void inputCar2(String Massege)
    {
        ShowMassage.println(Massege);
        ShowMassage.println("Enter Name of car manufactueing : ");
       //car2nd.manufacturerName=MyScanner.nextLine();
        car2nd.manufacturerName=MyScanner.nextLine();//problem indicated
        ShowMassage.println("Enter weight of car 2nd  :");
        car2nd.CarWeight=MyScanner.nextFloat();
        ShowMassage.println("Enter the amount of Fuel 2nd : ");
        car2nd.FuealAmount= MyScanner.nextFloat();
        ShowMassage.println("Enter the car 2nd  CC : ");
        car2nd.CarCC= MyScanner.nextInt();
        CarClass SeeCar1=new CarClass("1st car details: \n",car.manufacturerName,car.CarCC,car.FuealAmount,car.CarWeight);
        //2nd car
        CarClass See=new CarClass("2nd car details: \n",car2nd.manufacturerName,car2nd.CarCC,car2nd.FuealAmount,car2nd.CarWeight);
    }
}
```

Output :

```
Enter for first car: 
Enter Name of car manufactueing : 
lamborghini
Enter weight of car :
2222
Enter the amount of Fuel : 
2.369
Enter the car CC : 
236
Enter For 2nd Car : 
Enter Name of car manufactueing : 
Enter weight of car 2nd  :
263
Enter the amount of Fuel 2nd : 
3
Enter the car 2nd  CC : 
56
1st car details: 
Car Manufacturer Name : lamborghini
CC of Car : 236
Amount of fuel of car : 2.369
Weight of car : 2222.0
2nd car details: 
Car Manufacturer Name : 
CC of Car : 56
Amount of fuel of car : 3.0
Weight of car : 263.0
1st car details: 
Car Manufacturer Name : lamborghini
CC of Car : 236
Amount of fuel of car : 2.369
Weight of car : 2222.0
2nd car details: 
Car Manufacturer Name : 
CC of Car : 56
Amount of fuel of car : 3.0
Weight of car : 263.0
```

Comment: **Note:** according to java standards variable name should start with small letter and class name should start with capital letter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that when you press ENTER, you send a new line (`'\n'`) to the input buffer, and when you do `car.CarCC= MyScanner.nextInt();`, it will consume the digits but not the new line. So later, when you do `car2nd.manufacturerName=MyScanner.nextLine();` the `'\n'` is still in the input buffer and the `nextLine()` will consume that `'\n'` and immediately return an empty string.

The solution is to put a `MyScanner.nextLine();` somewhere between these two lines to consume that lost new line.

Comment: or always use `nextLine()` even when you try to get number (or whatever) - `Integer.parseInt(MyScanner.nextLine());`